# Finding a norm in $\mathbb R^2$ with a particular property.

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

I wanted to find a norm $N_1$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the map $N_2$ defined by $N_2(x,y)=N_1(|x|,|y|)$ does not define a norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Clearly the example of $N_1$ we are looking for will bring a problem in triangle inequality because the other two properties of norm will always be true. I tried the $p-$norms and the norm $N_1(x,y)=a |x|+b|y|$ with $a,b>0$ but all of them do not work. Please give an example of a norm where this is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $N_1(x,y) = \sqrt{(x-y)^2+y^2}$

Comment: It works for $(x,y)=(2,-1)$ and $(z,t)=(2,1)$ we can check that $N_2\big((x,y)+(z,t)\big) > N_2(x,y)+N_2(z,t)$.

Comment: @palio If you found my answer useful, you could accept it.